# using findByPk and WHERE condition in sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

In Sequelize I´m using findByPk but I also need to pass another condition

```
const options = {
    where: { role: 'admin' },
};

return models.User.findByPk(id, options)
    .then((user) => {...
```

But this query is retuning all users even if the role is not admin. I checked the SQL generated and I see
SELECT * from User WHERE id = 1 but I don´t see the AND role = 'admin'.
how to use findByPk and pass another condition?

thank you

Comment: Please don't forget to mark my answer as the accepted one if it helped you. Thanks!

Comment: @jknotek sorry I forgot. thanks for the reminder!

Comment: No problem, thank you!

Comment: This works.....

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You'll have to use `findOne` instead, and pass the primary key as a field in the `where` object:

```js
return models.User.findOne({
  where: {
    id: id,
    role: 'admin', 
  },
})
```

The Sequelize documentation can be a little cluttered... But, the `options` argument in `findByPk` doesn't take the same values as the one in `findOne`. If you look closely at the [documentation for findByPk](https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/model.js%7Emodel#static-method-findByPk), you'll see a note at the bottom that reads:

> See: Model.findAll for a full explanation of options, **Note that options.where is not supported**.